Как правильно реализовать Import и self в классах?
помогите пожалуйста разобраться. Вроде правильно понимал механику работы классов и вопрос банальный, но в упор не пойму что я делаю не правильно.
Делаю приложение на Python с GUI через tkinter.
Есть два файла. Один с классом главного меню StartPage и другой с классом билеты на вопросы Ticket_1
В первом файле я делаю импорт через код и в этом же файле есть всего один класс с функцией, которая вызывает проверку билета:
from Ticket_1 import Ticket_1


class StartPage():
    ...
    def check_access(self):
        Ticket_1.check()

А в файле с классом class Ticket_1() есть естественно функция проверить внутри себя билет  check и отправить итоги в первый файл:
def check(self): 
    right_counter = 0
    ... 
    return right_counter

Однако при запуске кода я получаю ошибку: Ticket_1.check() -> check() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
Как мне правильно ссылаться тогда в одном файле на функцию из другого?

Нужно больше кода. По описанию похоже, что check - это у вас метод внутри класса Ticket_1, но по фрагменту вашего кода этого не видно. Дальше, вы вызываете check от класса, значит никакой self автоматически заполняться не будет. Ну и не понятно, как ваш check должен понять, что ему нужно проверить.

На функцию вы уже успешно сослались, но к вам как к создателю функции логичный вопрос - что такое self? Если он вам не нужен - значит просто уберите его, наверное?

У меня в классе Ticket_1 есть метод init где есть несколько полей: self.entry которые потом передаются в функцию check(self). Однако при вызове функции этого класса (Ticket_1) из главного окна (StartPage) я получаю ошибку

Ticket_1.check() - это вызов метода класса без создания экземпляра класса. Поэтому когда вы так вызываете функцию, никакого self не передаётся - экземпляра же нет. Если вам ссылка на экземпляр класса self в этом методе реально нужна, то создайте экземпляр и вызывайте у него этот метод. А если не нужна, то уберите self из описания метода и вызывайте его как сейчас.

Ага, значит состояние экземпляра класса вам нужно. А где вы инициализируете экземпляр класса Ticket_1?

@CrazyElf огромное вам спасибо! я кажется понял, что вы имели в виду и всё заработало! Создал переменную экземпляр класса Ticket_1 и после этого он уже смог вызвать функцию... =)
